# javascript function call for single form

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple forms in my php file for different buttons. So, if I click on Back button, *ramesh.php* script should be called and so on. This is the code.

```
<form action="ramesh.php">
<input type="submit" value="Back" />
</form>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input name="rep_skyline" type="text" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<form action="update.php" method="post" >
<button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

However, I need to pass some data to server from my client side on form submit just for the **update** button. I have a javascript function to send the data to server side as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(e) {
var mydata = 3;
if ($(this).is(':not([data-submit="true"])'))
{
        $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="'+mydata+'">');
        $('form').data('submit', 'true').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
}    
})
})
</script>
```

If I click on the **update** button, the javascript function is working fine. However, if I click on **Back** or **Submit** button, I should not be calling the javascript function. Is there someway to do this?

Comment: why don't you use a link ?

Comment: why don't you use a more specific selector (by id for example) for affecting the function to the update form ?

Comment: also, why don't you put the hidden field directly in the form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your form an `id`:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" id="update-form">
```

Then use a more specific selector:

```
$("#update-form").submit(function() {
    // Code
});
```

I'm not quite sure why you need JavaScript to dynamically add data to your form, however. You should just use an `<input type="hidden" />` directly.

Answer (score 1):

`type=submit` will always load the form's action. Try to specify wich form to submit.

```
<form name="backForm" id="backForm" action="ramesh.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Back" />
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" action="process.php" method="post">
    <input name="rep_skyline" type="text" /> 
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now you can access the form via `document.backForm` or `document.getElementById("backForm")` and than use `submit();` like `document.getElementById("backForm").submit();`